# Make a section Visible on the action of Button from other section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm showing the data on tableview with multiple section,

[image]

when I open tableView height of section 1 should be 0. If I click a button in section 0 the height of the section 1 will be 150. For example if I click Agent button height of (want to) section cell show 150,I click builder button section hight will 0

I want to make the Section 1 visible on the button click from section 0

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! postaddTableViewCell1

            cell.ownerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FisrtButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.agentButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FisrtButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.builderButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FisrtButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell

        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! postaddTableViewCell2
            cell.checkbutton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.checkbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkbuttonClick) , for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell
        }
    }

  @objc func FisrtButtonClick(_ sender :UIButton)
    {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let cell = TableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? postaddTableViewCell1

        print(cell?.agentButton.titleLabel as Any)

        if sender.tag == 10
        {
            cell?.ownerButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.7254901961, blue: 0.4588235294, alpha: 1)
            cell?.agentButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.768627451, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.768627451, alpha: 1)
            cell?.builderButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.768627451, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.768627451, alpha: 1)
        }else if sender.tag == 11
        {
            cell?.ownerButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.768627451, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.768627451, alpha: 1)
            cell?.agentButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.7254901961, blue: 0.4588235294, alpha: 1)
            cell?.builderButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.768627451, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.768627451, alpha: 1)


        } else if sender.tag == 12
        {
            cell?.ownerButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.768627451, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.768627451, alpha: 1)
            cell?.agentButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.768627451, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.768627451, alpha: 1)
            cell?.builderButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.7254901961, blue: 0.4588235294, alpha: 1)
        }

    }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.section == 0
        {
            return 80
        }
        if indexPath.section == 1
        {
            return 0
        }
        return 80
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the required button is clicked in the `FisrtButtonClick` method and set a `boolean` that is accessible to `heightForRowAt`. After toggling the boolean you can just reload the section you require (also cleaned up your code lil bit).

```swift
var selectedAgent = false

@objc func firstButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.currentTitle == "Agent" {
        selectedAgent = true
        tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .automatic)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && !selectedAgent {
        return 0
    }
    return 80
}
```